# How can I set the height of a tinymce text area?

Tags: html, css, tinymce

I am using the following:

```
    <textarea
    data-ui-tinymce="tinymceOptions"
    data-ng-disabled="modal.action=='delete'"
    data-ng-model="modal.formData.text"
    id="inputText"
    rows="20"
    required></textarea>
```

When the tinymce appears the height is just a few centimeters. How can I change the height of the default when it first appears?

Here is a list of the options I am using:

```
selector: "textarea",           
plugins: [
                        "advlist autolink autosave link image lists charmap print preview hr anchor pagebreak spellchecker",
                        "searchreplace wordcount visualblocks visualchars code fullscreen insertdatetime media nonbreaking",
                        "table contextmenu template textcolor paste fullpage textcolor"
                ],

                toolbar1: "bold italic underline strikethrough | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | styleselect fontselect fontsizeselect",
                toolbar2: "cut copy paste | searchreplace | bullist numlist | outdent indent blockquote | undo redo | code | inserttime preview | forecolor backcolor",
                toolbar3: "table | hr removeformat | subscript superscript | charmap | print fullscreen | spellchecker | visualchars visualblocks nonbreaking template pagebreak restoredraft",

                menubar: false,
                toolbar_items_size: 'small',

                templates: [
                        {title: 'Test template 1', content: 'Test 1'},
                        {title: 'Test template 2', content: 'Test 2'}
```

]

Comment: Can you simulate the same on jsfiddle (http://jsfiddle.net) or add the screen shot,so that its easy to understand :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should set height of container object in CSS:

```
#inputText {
    height : 10000000px;
}
```

Comment: Word to the wise: This won't work if the textarea is hidden when the tinyMCE initialization script runs. (By "hidden," I mean the textarea or one of its ancestors is set to "display: none.") When initializing, tinyMCE measures the height of the textarea onscreen, then replaces it with an iframe and gives the iframe the same height via an inline style ("height: 300px"). If your textarea is, for example, located inside a modal window that is set to "display: none" when you initialize the editor, tinyMCE will measure the textarea's height as zero and won't assign an inline height to the iframe.

Answer (score 29):

from javascript

```
tinymce.init({
   selector: 'textarea',
   height: 200
});
```

OR from html

```
<textarea style="height: 200px;">
```

Comment: this should be the correct answer, this addresses the problem mentioned by Dan Robinson as comment on the currently selected Answer

Comment: This worked for me, but I needed to remove any autoresize property from the config to make it work.

Answer (score 2):

for tinyMCE version **before** 4.X then this code is working

```
tinyMCE.init({
    ...,
    setup: function(editor) {
        editor.onInit.add(function() {
            var width = editor.getWin().clientWidth;
            var height = 50;

            editor.theme.resizeTo(width, height);
        });
    }
});
```

for tinyMCE version 4.X and **after** then this code is working

```
tinyMCE.init({
   setup: function (ed) {
      ed.on('init', function(args) {
         var id = ed.id;
         var height = 25;

         document.getElementById(id + '_ifr').style.height = height + 'px';
      });
   }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

For global height setting for TinyMCE, edit settings.py of Django project:

```
TINYMCE_DEFAULT_CONFIG = {'height': 120}
```

For per-widget settings, use `mce_attrs` in form class:

```
input = forms.CharField(widget=TinyMCE(mce_attrs={'height': 120}))
```

Tested with django-tinymce 2.7.0.

**Under the hood:** You can see string like `&quot;height&quot;: 120,` in data-mce-conf attribute of the generated HTML for the textarea. Otherwise, something goes wrong.

Answer (score 1):

For version 6 the following code should work

```
const wishedHeight = '100px'
// get `editor` from context of callbacks like `init`, `setup`, `loaded`, etc 
editor.editorContainer.style.height = wishedHeight;
```

Answer (score 0):

It works for me (see **setTimeout** part)

```js
$(function () {
    window.init_tinymce = function (id, custom_config) {
        var textarea = $('#' + id);

        // Default TinyMCE configuration
        var basic_config = {
            mode: 'none',
            plugins: "link",
            menu: 'none',
            toolbar: 'bold | formatselect | link'
        };

        tinymce.init($.extend(basic_config, custom_config));
        ...

        setTimeout(function(){ //wait for tinymce to load
            console.log('timeout');
            $(tinymce.editors[0].iframeElement).contents().find('body')
                .css('min-height', $(tinymce.editors[0].contentAreaContainer).height() * .9);
        }, 1000);
    };
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this css to your custom style sheet otherwise it will decrease all existing editors' height.

```
.mce-edit-area iframe {
    max-height: 200px;
}
```